# Can't make a shortcut to work (properly)

Tags: command-line, sudo, shortcuts, pycharm

I made a shortcut for PyCharm following this [instruction](http://www.linuxrussia.com/2013/09/shortcut-ubuntu-sh.html) (created a *.desktop file; before that I launched the application via terminal by `sudo sh pycharm.sh` comand). However, the shortcut I made doesn't work properly - if I launch it from Dash the application will be launched but will not work and freeze. The same will happen if I launch application via terminal by `sh pycharm.sh`. But, if I launch the application via terminal with `sudo sh pycharm.sh` comand, close it and then use shortcut, everything will work smoothly.

How can I make the shortcut work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `sudo` in the `.desktop` file with `gksudo`.

This is because `sudo` cannot ask you the password outside the terminal, but the command needs `sudo` access so it freezes on the `sudo` step (apparently still waiting for the password).

`gksudo` will graphically prompt you for the password.

Update: To execute without password:

We need to set `nopasswd` on that script.

1. Edit `/etc/sudoers` with the command `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers`
2. Add the line:

   ```
   %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/script.sh
   ```

   Replacing `/full/path/to/script.sh` with the actual full path.
3. Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and quit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

Now you should be able to run it without password. Also, you can now even use `sudo` instead of `gksudo`.

Comment: Than you @Bharadwai_Raju, this helped!
By the way, what can I do to elude entering password everytime?

Comment: @user48115 See my update to the answer.